# AngularJS - Dropdown filtering doesn't update when using 'track by $index'

Tags: angularjs

**HTML:**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="row in pagemodel.Tiering|filteraggregator">
    <!-- more stuff here...  -->
    <select class="form-control" name="paramType" ng-change="setParamC(row.RowID)" ng-model="row.ParameterT" ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamTList track by $index" required></select>

    <select class="form-control" name="paramCat" ng-change="validatePCat(row.RowID)" ng-model="row.ParameterC" ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamCList|filter:{ReferenceParentCode:row.ParameterT.ReferenceCode , ReferenceParentDomain:row.ParameterT.ReferenceDomain} track by $index" required></select>

    <select class="form-control" name="paramName" ng-change="setParamV(row.RowID,0)" ng-model="row.ParameterN" ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamNList|filter:{ReferenceParentCode:row.ParameterC.ReferenceCode , ReferenceParentDomain:row.ParameterC.ReferenceDomain} track by $index" required></select>

</tbody>
```

**Angular-JS:**

```
tieringController.prototype.setParamC = function(index) {
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("frmtiering")).scope();

    scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ParameterC="";
    scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ParameterN = "";
    scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ParameterValue = "";
    scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ValidatePc = false;
}

tieringController.prototype.validatePCat = function (index) {
    // this complex code merely looks for duplicate combinations in the dropdown settings
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("frmtiering")).scope();
    scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ValidatePc = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < scope.pagemodel.Tiering.length; i++) {
        if (i != index && scope.pagemodel.Tiering[i].IsActive) {
            if (scope.pagemodel.Tiering[i].AggregatorName == scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].AggregatorName
            && scope.pagemodel.Tiering[i].ParameterC == scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ParameterC) {
            if(scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ParameterN !='' && (scope.pagemodel.Tiering[i].ParameterN == scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ParameterN))  {
                scope.pagemodel.Tiering[index].ValidatePc = true;
                scope.submitted = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a list of data objects that are returned from the server to the front end via an ajax call.

Each object contains three properties (`ParameterT`, `ParameterC` and `ParameterN`) that point to other child objects.  Each one of these properties is the initial value of a dropdown.  In order for that binding to work, I had to add `track by $index`, but doing that "broke" my filtering.

I'm using filtering to update the available options in the second and third dropdown.  So, the setting of the first dropdown causes the second dropdown to display a different set of options via filtering.  The setting of the second dropdown causes the third dropdown to display a different set of options via filtering.

This works properly when the `track by $index` is NOT included.  When I include `track by $index`, the filtering no longer works.  The initial set of options are properly included in the list, but when the first dropdown is changed, it no longer updates the set of options for the second dropdown.

**EDIT:**

Without `track by $index` this is what my dropdowns look like:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" name="paramType" ng-change="setParamC(row.RowID)" ng-model="row.ParameterT" ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamTList" required="">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="Static" value="object:478">Static</option>
    <option label="Dynamic" value="object:479">Dynamic</option>
</select>
```

With `track by $index` this is what my dropdowns look like:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" name="paramType" ng-change="setParamC(row.RowID)" ng-model="row.ParameterT" ng-options="item.ReferenceValue for item in pagemodel.ParamTList track by $index" required="">
    <option label="Static" value="0">Static</option>
    <option label="Dynamic" value="0" selected="selected">Dynamic</option>
</select>
```

you'll notice that with `track by $index` causes my option value to be zero.  That's probably why the cascading dropdowns are not filtering correctly.

So... did I do something wrong?

Comment: `$index` is undefined at the `select` level.  Pass the selected object instead `ng-change="setParamC(row.ParameterT)"`.  Or one of its properties.

Comment: Good catch... unfortunately, I left out a part of the HTML.  Those three elements are surrounded by a repeating element.  I'll add some more,,,